# Memory Leak - Singly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind, singly-linked-list

I implement this simple code for implement a Singly linked list in C. I just post another question for this code ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973317/c-linked-list-of-hash-table-keys)). 
I put the code the same so that you can see it without having to change pages. This is the code:

#### struct of a list node:

```
struct hash_table_key_list_node_s {
  char *key;
  struct hash_table_key_list_node_s* next;
};

typedef struct hash_table_key_list_node_s hash_table_key_list_node_t;
typedef hash_table_key_list_node_t* hash_table_key_list_t;
```

#### code of the function:

```
hash_table_key_list_t hash_table_keys(hash_table_t hash_table) {

  hash_table_key_list_t list, tail, p;
  list = tail = NULL;

  if ( hash_table != NULL && hash_table->slots != NULL ) {

    size_t index = 0;
    while ( index < hash_table->capacity ) {

      hash_table_list_node_t *node = hash_table->slots[index].head;
      while ( node != NULL ) {

        p = malloc(sizeof(hash_table_key_list_node_t));
        p->key = malloc((strlen(node->key) + 2) * sizeof(char));
        if ( p->key == NULL ) {
          perror("Unable to allocate a key\n");
          abort();  
        }

        strcpy(p->key, node->key);

        if ( node != NULL ) {
          list = tail = p;
        }
        else { 
          tail->next = p;
          tail = p;
        }

        node = node->next;
      }

      index++;
    }
  }

  return list; 
}
```

#### function for destroy list

```
void destroy_key_list(hash_table_key_list_t key_list) {

  hash_table_key_list_node_t *current = NULL;

  if ( key_list == NULL ) return;

  while ( key_list != NULL ) {
    current = key_list;
    free(current->key);
    free(current);

    key_list = key_list->next;
  }

  free(key_list);
}
```

I have two problem that I don't understand:

- Why does the list no longer contain nodes once the list that returns to the function is used? Is it for the type of list?
- Why does it generate me memery loss? I tried calling the `free` function on the`node` variable before incrementing the `index` variable but nothing changes.

This is the output of valgrind after one calling of the function:

```
==10757== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10757==     in use at exit: 15,840 bytes in 660 blocks
==10757==   total heap usage: 1,329 allocs, 669 frees, 123,642 bytes allocated
==10757== 
==10757== 5,264 bytes in 329 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 3
==10757==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10757==    by 0x10B93E: hash_table_keys (in /media/psf/bioinformatics-assignment-1/app/main)
==10757==    by 0x109B27: main (in /media/psf/bioinformatics-assignment-1/app/main)
==10757== 
==10757== 10,560 bytes in 330 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 3
==10757==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10757==    by 0x10B975: hash_table_keys (in /media/psf/bioinformatics-assignment-1/app/main)
==10757==    by 0x109B27: main (in /media/psf/bioinformatics-assignment-1/app/main)
==10757== 
==10757== 15,840 (16 direct, 15,824 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==10757==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10757==    by 0x10B93E: hash_table_keys (in /media/psf/bioinformatics-assignment-1/app/main)
==10757==    by 0x109B27: main (in /media/psf/bioinformatics-assignment-1/app/main)
```

Here you can find all the sources and headers file:

- [hash_table.c](https://pastebin.com/4b9zbZ1g) (there are the implementation of all function)
- [hash_table_private.h](https://pastebin.com/k6u53tzC) (private header, where are the struct definition)
- [hash_table.h](https://pastebin.com/TCvJRw3R) (public header, where are the function prototipe)

Comment: don't forget that `strdup` also allocates memory on the heap that needs to be freed.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Do I have to call the `free` function on the` p` variable before scrolling `node`?

Comment: No. Unless you are deleting the node from your list. Otherwise your list will contain pointers to nodes which are invalid.

Comment: An [mcve] would be helpful

Comment: @MFisherKDX Sorry, I forgot to put the function to destroy the list. I just edit the question.

Comment: `current = key_list; free(current->key); free(current); key_list = key_list->next;` --> change to `next = key_list->next; free(key_list->key); free(key_list); key_list = next;`

Comment: @MFisherKDX I don't know why, but the problem persist

Comment: It's a very low chance this free issue is causing the problem you describe. Unfortunately you haven't provided a [mcve] so it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I just update the question. I add a link to the source code.

Comment: If you remove the `typedef`s, I think it will be clearer to read. You could replace `struct hash_table_key_list_node_s; typedef struct hash_table_key_list_node_s hash_table_key_list_node_t; typedef hash_table_key_list_node_t* hash_table_key_list_t;` with something like `struct hash_node`.

Answer (score 2):

Careful here:

```
while ( key_list != NULL ) {
    current = key_list; // current is now a copy of key_list (a copy of the pointer)
    free(current->key);
    free(current);      // here you free current and hence key_list

    key_list = key_list->next; // here you are referring to key_list, just freed above
  }
```

Try this instead:

```
while ( key_list != NULL ) {
    current = key_list; 
    key_list = key_list->next; 
    free(current->key);
    free(current);      
  }
```

There may be other errors in your code, but this was one.

Comment: The error persist...
Reading the valgrind error I suppose that one problem is the malloc in the function for create list